# Fix exception and rerun function

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

How can we fix an exception and rerun the exact function that threw the exception?
For example, in Selenium if there is a inline popup window that appears randomly on the website, we may get a NoSuchElement exception. I want to catch that exception, fix it (by closing the popup window), and then rerun the exact line of the program that threw the exception. How can I do this?

Comment: Use [`try`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) and [`catch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) clauses.

Comment: Yep, I guess my question is how to I rerun the line that errored in the catch clause?

Comment: Why do you not catch the exception, fix whatever went wrong, and call the method again?

Comment: Because I'm using the "catch" to fix randomly occurring popups by closing them. If I fix it on the current page/state of my Selenium workflow, then I rerun my entire Selenium process again, it won't work when I rerun the process unless I start at the offending line (the second time I start the process the popup will reappear).

Comment: instead of catching the exception, the alternative would just be a simple if statement.  if the popup is present, then close the popup.

Comment: if its not an option you cannot set if in every row of your code, i think you need to use design pattern for this case. (try to look at Observer pattern)